# How to fetch facebook friend list in android ? I am using facebook sdk 4.0.1

Tags: android

I am using facebook sdk 4.0 for android application. Want to fetch facebook friend list.

Comment: have a look at this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/friendlist)

Comment: @ Aawaz  Thanks, But using this way it will showing only those friend who using this app, but I want all friend list of facebook.