# Unable to get friend list from Facebook in Android. Getting blank array with count

Tags: android

I have tried using these references:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends

[How to get friend list from Facebook using Android Facebook sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656046/how-to-get-friend-list-from-facebook-using-android-facebook-sdk)

[How to fetch facebook friend list in android ? I am using facebook sdk 4.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702611/how-to-fetch-facebook-friend-list-in-android-i-am-using-facebook-sdk-4-0-1)

I have also tried other references but I could not get a solution for my issue.

Here is my code

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                    System.out.println("Facebook recponse = "+response);

                    try {
                        sSocialId = object.getString("id");
                        if (object.has("email")) {
                            sEmail = object.getString("email");
                        }
                        sSocialType = "fb";
                        sFirstname = object.getString("first_name");
                        sLastname = object.getString("last_name");
                        String gender = object.getString("gender");
                        sGender = gender;
                        sUserImageUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + sSocialId + "/picture?type=large";

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    AccessToken token1   =  AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                    /*
                     make the API call
                    */

                    new GraphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            "/me/friendlists",
                            null,
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                                    try {
                                        JSONArray rawName = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");

                                        String  friendList = "{\"friendlist\":" + rawName.toString() + "}";
                                        Log.d("TAG","response of friendlist is : " + friendList);

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    ).executeAsync();

                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"Login successfull...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name,gender, email,picture,friends{id,name,picture}");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Facebook login cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Error in Facebook login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getFriendList(String id) { //fbId 
    fbFriendsList = new ArrayList<>();
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/" + id + "/friends",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.e("response", response.toString());

                    try {
                        JSONArray frienArray = ((JSONArray) (response.getJSONObject().get("data")));
                        for (int i = 0; i < frienArray.length(); i++) {
                            FbFriends fbFriends = new FbFriends();
                            JSONObject jsonObject = frienArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            fbFriends.setFbId(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                            fbFriendsList.add(fbFriends);

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        /* handle the result */


                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();


}
```

here fbFreindsList is a List of modelClass fbFriends , here i'm taking only id of fbfriends, you can also get data according to your requirement

Comment: thanks for answering my question, but still i am facing same problem.

Comment: only get total_count but data is empty